# What does `cache = obj.cache = {}` do in this decorator?

Tags: python, memoization

The following decorator memoizes a function that's been passed to it. I'm not understanding what the first line of this decorator is doing. How is it able to assign a value to `obj.cache` if there's no guarantee it exists?

```
  def memoize(obj):
    cache = obj.cache = {}

    @functools.wraps(obj)
    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[args]
    return memoizer
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  You don't need to know if if `obj.cache` exists to *assign* a value to it.  Assigning a value means you give it a value, whether it was there before or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it seems your question doesn't really have anything to do with the multiple assignment.  You're just wondering how `obj.cache = {}` can work if `obj` has no attribute called `cache`.

The answer is that in Python, attributes don't need to be predeclared.  Unless you code your class specially to be more restrictive, you can assign any attribute on any instance of any user-defined class at any time.  If the attribute doesn't already exist, it will be created with the new value.

Comment: And the ways to make it more restrictive include (but are not limited to) 1) writing it in C/<underlying language> and not having a `__dict__` attribute, and 2) defining the `__slots__` attribute in a Python type.

Comment: Also writing a `__setattr__` that disallows it.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, setting a property that doesn't exist *creates* that property. I think most dynamic languages work that way. So `cache = obj.cache = {}` creates the property `cache` on `obj` setting it to `{}`.